# How to Get Current NetworkInterfaceInfo

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone-8

I'd like to be able to determine how the device is currently connected, whether it be cellular, wifi, Ethernet, etc. My main question is, do I have to open a socket using `socket.GetCurrentNetworkInterface()` or can I simply use the `NetworkInterfaceInfo` class and determine how the device is currently connected? What I need to do is determine how the device is connected when the application starts, and then have this data updated as changes occur with device connectivity. How might I be able to accomplish this to always know how the device is currently connected?

Comment: But -- there may be more than one connection available -- a cell and wifi for example.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to be aware of changes in Network connectivity you will want to use the [DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation.networkavailabilitychanged%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event.

You do not need to open a socket, I would suggest iterating through the [NetworkInterfaceList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.networkinterfacelist%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which is a collection of [NetworkInterfaceInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.networkinterfaceinfo%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) objects. With each Network Interface see if it is connected, and if it is see what type of Network Interface it is. Here's some sample code:

```
NetworkStateTracker()
{
  DetermineNetworkState();
  DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged;
}

void OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged(object sender, NetworkNotificationEventArgs args)
{
  DetermineNetworkState();
}

void DetermineNetworkState()
{
  bool bIsCellularConnected = false;
  bool bIsWiFiConnected = false;
  NetworkInterfaceList netInfoList = new NetworkInterfaceList();
  foreach (NetworkInterfaceInfo netInfo in netInfoList)
  {
    if (netInfo.InterfaceState == ConnectState.Connected)
    {
      switch (netInfo.InterfaceType)
      {
        case NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandCdma:
        case NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandGsm:
          bIsCellularConnected = true;
          break;
        case NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211:
          bIsWiFiConnected = true;
      }
    }
  }
  // Do something with the Network
}
```